# HTML JavaScript localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```
if(localStorage.getItem('arr')){
    document.getElementById("scores").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('arr');
}

var stored_arr = JSON.parse(localStorage["arr"]);
document.getElementById("scores").innerHTML += stored_arr;

var newarr = stored_arr.split(",");
document.getElementById("scores").innerHTML += newarr[0];
```

Here's a snippet of code. It checks for localStorage and it it exists prints it out(for testing). Then it parses it and stores it in the stored_arr variable, and also displays it. At this point it would have

> ["xxxxxxx","yyyyyyy"]xxxxx,yyyyy

displayed, where xxxxx,yyyy is contained in the stored_arr variable. I need a way to split that up by the comma and tried the final two lines of code and nothing happens.

Am I wrong to use JSON.parse() or is it the way I'm trying to split it?

Comment: if you are parsing the value at `arr` then you already have an array and don't need to split. Try throwing a `console.log('stored arr', stored_arr)` after you get/parse the value from local storage to see what you are really getting

Comment: Idk why I didn't realize or even try that. Thanks